# Configurable product images not working

Tags: magento, configurable

Would anyone know how i can get the images from associated products in a configurable product to show on the frontend of a magento website. I've tried numerous ideas but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this we need to create a extension, so that we can fetch the associated product's image when a customer select option in configurable product.

Like:- Product name is "Shirt" and you have two colors "Red and Green" with two sizes "M and L". So you should have 4 simple products i.e associated products:-

1. Red-M
2. Red-L
3. Green-M
4. Green-L

So when a customer will select a 'Red' and 'M' from select box then we will change its main image to the selected product's image i.e image of Red-M product.

Comment: Hi guys, I've done all that. i've created a simple with all three attributes in it, but when i select all three fields the image doesn't change. i've tried all sorts of modules and tricks but none work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System-> Magento Connect->Magento Connect Manager, download the extension of netstarter_imageswitcher and install it.
   (Eg:http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Netstarter_Imageswitcher)
2. Go to System -> Configuration , Under Catalog, select Configurable swatches and do the following:

In General settings,
Set Enabled to Yes
Set Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail to the attributes which you have created.

3. Save the configuration